# what's the species identification of that camponotus queen

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

City: [Antalya, Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antalya)

Date: July 27 night

Specific location: I found it in the middle of the city

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In what kind of environment / ecosystem did you find them?

Comment: antalya, turkey ... summer +40 celcius, winter 10 celsius on avarege. seaside , and haliday city. There mediterranean coast. if you write antalya on google picturen you may see . :)

Comment: I meant "micro-environment" (I should have been clearer). In the middle of the forest in the shade of large trees, right up on the beach, in the middle of the city, in houses as pest, etc...

Comment: sory :) . I found it in the middle of the city. when I dronk a cup coffee she drop my table on the July 27 night .